# Не работает скрипт

Tags: jquery

Не работает скрипт из учебника, изображение должно "падать" вниз страницы и исчезать.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.animateMe').each(function(){
        $(this)
        .css('position','relative')
        .animate(
            {
            opacity: 0,
            top: $(window).height() - $(this).height()
                 $(this).position().top
            },
            'slow',
            function(){ $(this).hide(); });
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T4N7K/8/
Проверка скрипта выдает, что в нем есть ошибки, но я не могу разобраться, в чем они заключается. Пример в точности как в учебнике.

Comment: А саму jQuery Вы случайно не забыли?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('.animateMe').each(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        $(this)
        .css('position','relative')
        .animate(
            {
            opacity: 0,
            top: $(window).height() - img.height()
                // $(this).position().top
            },
            'slow',
            function(){ $(this).hide(); });
    });
});
```

Не работает по двум причинам:

1 - Что значит эта строка, она не вычитается ничего, $(this).position().top

2 - $(this) в функции анимейт не указывает на объект имг. поэтому выносим его в переменную выше var img = $(this);

Answer (score 0):

возможно так будет работать?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function(){
    $('.animateMe').each(function(){
        $(this)
        .css('position','relative')
        .animate(
            {
            opacity: 0,
            top: $(window).height() - $(this).height()
                 $(this).position().top
            },
            'slow',
            function(){ $(this).hide(); });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: нет, тоже не работает.  
$(document).ready(function() {...} эквивалентно $(function(){...}

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.animateMe').each(function(){
        $(this)
        .css('position','relative')
        .animate(
            {
            opacity: 0,
            top: function(){
                   return $(window).height() - $(this).height();
                 }
            },
            'slow',
            function(){ $(this).hide(); });
    });
});
</script>
```